# Deserialize Complex JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON String:

[Link to JSON String](http://docs.ninja.is/rest/device.html#device-get-devices)

```
{
  "result": 1,
  "error": null,
  "id": 0,
  "data": {
    "ASTEALTHYNODE01_0301_0_30": {
        "css_class": "sensor rf digital humidity",
        "default_name": "Humidity",
        "device_type": "humidity",
        "did": "30",
        "gid": "0301",
        "has_subdevice_count": 0,
        "has_time_series": 1,
        "is_actuator": 0,
        "is_sensor": 1,
        "is_silent": 0,
        "last_data": {
            "DA": 58,
            "timestamp": 1355791804474
        },
        "meta": {},
        "node": "ASTEALTHYNODE01",
        "shortName": "Humidity",
        "subDevices": {},
        "vid": "0"
    },
    "ASTEALTHYNODE01_0301_0_31": {
        "css_class": "sensor rf digital temperature",
        "default_name": "Temperature",
        "device_type": "temperature",
        "did": "31",
        "gid": "0301",
        "has_subdevice_count": 0,
        "has_time_series": 1,
        "is_actuator": 0,
        "is_sensor": 1,
        "is_silent": 0,
        "last_data": {
            "DA": 26.6,
            "timestamp": 1355791804475
        },
        "meta": {},
        "node": "ASTEALTHYNODE01",
        "shortName": "Temperature",
        "subDevices": {},
        "vid": "0"
    },
    "ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_1000": {
        "css_class": "actuator cape led rgbled",
        "default_name": "On Board RGB LED",
        "device_type": "rgbled",
        "did": "1000",
        "gid": "0",
        "has_subdevice_count": 0,
        "has_time_series": 0,
        "is_actuator": 1,
        "is_sensor": 1,
        "is_silent": 0,
        "last_data": {
            "DA": "22B42B",
            "timestamp": 1355790209080
        },
        "meta": {},
        "node": "ASTEALTHYNODE01",
        "shortName": "On Board RGB LED",
        "subDevices": {},
        "vid": "0"
    },
    "ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11": {
        "css_class": "sensor serial rf rf433 receiver transmitter",
        "default_name": "RF 433Mhz",
        "device_type": "rf433",
        "did": "11",
        "gid": "0",
        "has_subdevice_count": 1,
        "has_time_series": 0,
        "is_actuator": 1,
        "is_sensor": 1,
        "is_silent": 0,
        "last_data": {
            "DA": "010001010101010100010101",
            "timestamp": 1355789891324
        },
        "meta": {},
        "node": "ASTEALTHYNODE01",
        "shortName": "RF 433Mhz",
        "subDevices": {
            "6l8At": {
                "category": "rf",
                "data": "011111110001010100110000",
                "shortName": "Door Bell",
                "type": "sensor"
            }
        },
        "vid": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

I usually create the classes with help of: http://json2csharp.com and then I am doing something like this (Json.NET libary):
Collapse | Copy Code

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString);
```

But the number of devices and their names (example: ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11) are unknown before I get the JSON string. How can i deserialize this ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered creating a loop that sends each to the code-behind and stores the deserialized object in a list(of type) property? Not sure if you can store the prop in viewstate or not though

Comment: You you are targeting a recent version of the .NET framework, this may be one of those cases where it makes sense to deserialize you JSON into a `dynamic` object (```dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);``` )

Comment: @Lopsided Im sorry but I don't get it. Could you wirte some pseudo code or explain it more detailed? Thank you

Comment: @Mauro Cerutt The dynamic object looks very interesting ! I will give it a try. Thank you

Comment: I actually assumed you were using the "dynamic" object. I should explain, the only reason I didn't post this as an answer is because I have only been using newtonsoft's JSON.net framework for a few months, it is for VB.net, and I haven't really played around too much with it yet (so I don't know all the terminology, tricks, etc). Currently I use it to overcome ASP.NET Web APIs' inability to accept multiple parameters for post actions. Instead I just use one parameter (a stringified JSON object) and then deserialize it to access all my properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, with your JSON, and using JSON.NET:

```
        Payload payloadJsonNet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(data);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert
        (
            payloadJsonNet.data.ContainsKey("ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11") &&
            payloadJsonNet.data["ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11"].subDevices.ContainsKey("6l8At") &&
            payloadJsonNet.data["ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11"].subDevices["6l8At"].shortName == "Door Bell"
        );
```

... provided you have prepared the following POCOs (using the nifty [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) helper, for example):

```
    public class Payload
    {
        public int result { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Error error { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Device> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public string css_class { get; set; }
        public string default_name { get; set; }
        public string device_type { get; set; }
        public string did { get; set; }
        public string gid { get; set; }
        public int has_subdevice_count { get; set; }
        public int has_time_series { get; set; }
        public int is_actuator { get; set; }
        public int is_sensor { get; set; }
        public int is_silent { get; set; }
        public LastData last_data { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public string node { get; set; }
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Device> subDevices { get; set; }
        public string vid { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastData
    {
        public string DA { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
    }

    public class Error
    {
    }
```

I guess you'll have to find out / infer from other JSON inputs what should be the properties for these last two guys (i.e., "Meta" and "Error").

Note also, the "long" type that needs to be used in:

```
    public class LastData
    {
        public string DA { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally, just for the curious, [my own parser](https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser#Overview) deserializes it fine as well:

```
        Payload payloadMyParser = new JsonParser().Parse<Payload>(data);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert
        (
            payloadMyParser.data.ContainsKey("ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11") &&
            payloadMyParser.data["ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11"].subDevices.ContainsKey("6l8At") &&
            payloadMyParser.data["ASTEALTHYNODE01_0_0_11"].subDevices["6l8At"].shortName == "Door Bell"
        );
```

'Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Your json "data" property looks like property with type Dictionary < string, SomeClass>, where SomeClass - is a class for

```
    {
        "css_class": "sensor rf digital humidity",
// skipped
       "subDevices": {},
        "vid": "0"
    },
```

data structure, so you may define this property in MyObject class and use strong typed deserialization without any problem.